# tkinter counting number of displayed lines

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk

out = """Line 1: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
Line 2: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac. Etiam dignissim diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque. Metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper. """

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("980x720")
text = tk.Text(root, wrap = "word", font=("TkDefaultFont",18))
text.pack(side="top", fill="x")
text.insert("end", out)


num_lines = text.count("1.0", "end", "displaylines")[0]
print(f"initial num lines: {num_lines}")
text.configure(height=num_lines)

def test(event):
    num_lines = text.count("1.0", "end", "displaylines")[0]
    print("num lines:", num_lines)
    text.configure(height=num_lines)

text.bind('<MouseWheel>', test)

root.mainloop()
```

I have a tk.Text widget that will be on a scrollable frame, and so should have its height set to the number of lines in the text, depending on the window size so that it does not need to be scrolled.

In this test case, the string is 2 lines but with the initial window size, this takes up 4 lines after wrapping. However, initially the num_lines returns 255 instead of 4 (in console output) so the widget height is not configured correctly.

Only when calling test() by hovering over the text widget and moving the scroll wheel, then the text widget will have its height set correctly depending on the window size.

How can this be set correctly from the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `num_lines` calculation is being performed before the text widget has been rendered on the screen. As a result, it's returning an incorrect value.

Add `root.update()` after `text.insert("end", out)` and you'll be fine.

Hopes that help you.

Comment: It's not so much that it's returning an incorrect value, as that the correct value  can't be defined until the window is actually rendered on screen.